# Creating multiple workspace layout for Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

You know that Android Studio has a `Default layout` that is editable (by replacing it by current layout).

My question:

Is it possible to define some layouts for Android Studio with different names along it's default layout and use them in appropriate situation?

Please don’t confuse custom layout for `Android Studio` with layouts in the `Android SDK`. In the main menu of Android Studio you can see `Window >> store current layout as default` and `Window >> Restore default layout`. So it seems that the word `Layout` is used in `Android Studio` about the arrangement of windows/panes within it and I use that word too.

Comment: When I [search the Android Studio help for `layout`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/meet-intellij-idea.html?search=layout), pretty much everything refers to what I would call "layouts in the Android SDK". Please explain precisely what "custom layout for Android Studio" means, given that neither JetBrains nor Google seem to be using that term.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? I think you are asking about the arrangement of windows/panes within Android Studio. Perhaps some example screen shots will help us understand what you are asking about.

Comment: Please see my question again, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there doesn't seem to be an option for saving multiple window layouts in Android Studio. I have looked and tried.

The only documentation I have found for window/toolbar layouts is from the [IntelliJ Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html?search=window):

> **Saving and restoring the arrangement of the tool windows**
>
> You can save the way the tool window are currently arranged by
>    choosing Window | Store Current Layout as Default in the main menu.
>
> At a later time, you can return to the saved workspace layout by
>    choosing Window | Restore Default Layout <kbd>⇧</kbd> +
>    <kbd>F12</kbd>.